# how to reset a cumulative sum based on date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe looking like `df`:

```
date   way 
date_1 A
date_1 B
date_1 A 
date_2 A 
date_2 A 
date_2 A
```

I want to add a `journey` column based on theses conditions : it's a cumulative sum that increment when `way` or `date` are not the same from a row to the next one and reset the cum sum when `date` are changing

I already have :

```
(df['journey']=df['date'].ne(df['date'].shift())) |(df['way'].ne(df['way'].shift()))).cumsum()
```

which get the cumulative sum when `date` or `way` are changing. How can i add the reset when `date` are changing ?

the expected result is :

```
date   way journey
date_1 A    1
date_1 B    2
date_1 A    3
date_2 A    1
date_2 A    1
date_2 A    1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df['journey']= df['way'].ne(df['way'].shift().bfill()).groupby(df['date']).cumsum().add(1)
print (df)
     date way  journey
0  date_1   A        1
1  date_1   B        2
2  date_1   A        3
3  date_2   A        1
4  date_2   A        1
5  date_2   A        1
```

Or:

```
df['journey'] = (df[['date', 'way']].ne(df[['date', 'way']].shift())
                   .any(axis=1).groupby(df['date']).cumsum())

print (df)
     date way  journey
0  date_1   A        1
1  date_1   B        2
2  date_1   A        3
3  date_2   A        1
4  date_2   A        1
5  date_2   A        1
```

Your solution:

```
df['journey'] = ((df['date'].ne(df['date'].shift()) |(df['way'].ne(df['way'].shift())))
                   .groupby(df['date']).cumsum())

print (df)
     date way  journey
0  date_1   A        1
1  date_1   B        2
2  date_1   A        3
3  date_2   A        1
4  date_2   A        1
5  date_2   A        1
```

Comment: Your second solution is exactly what i need, Thanks !